# Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am able to fetch data from `get_result()` using any of `fetch_assoc()`, `fetch_all()`, ..., and `fetch_row()` but when I am trying to use the simple `fetch()` only, I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Is this because of using `get_result()`?  or am I missing something else in the following code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($SQL);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
//$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
//$row = $result->fetch_all();
//$row = $result->fetch_row();
$row = $result->fetch();
```

Comment: There is no `fetch()` method on the [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. You're probably looking at the `fetch()` method of the [mysqli_stmt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) object.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I believe you can make it an answer. However low-effort, it's a fair question and, as far as I can tell, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `$stmt` is an object of the [`mysqli_stmt`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) class. This class has a method called [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) which returns a boolean (true/false). It is used only in conjunction with [`bind_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT myCol, myOtherCol FROM myTable WHERE dt=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date);
$stmt->execute();
// The columns in SQL will be bound to the PHP variables
$stmt->bind_result($variable1, $variable2);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // This will fetch each record from the prepared statement one by one
    printf ("myCol is %s and myOtherCol is %s\n", $variable1, $variable1);
}
```

[`$stmt->get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) returns an object of class [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) (which by the way is traversable using `foreach`). This class has different methods, but it doesn't have `fetch()` method.

- [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) return an array of arrays. As the name suggests it returns all records from the result set at once.

  ```
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $allRecords = $result->fetch_all(\MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($allRecords);
  ```
- [`fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns each record one by one as an 1D array

  ```
  $row = $result->fetch_array();
  printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["myCol"], $row["myOtherCol"]);
  ```
- [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) is the equivalent to `fetch_array(\MYSQLI_ASSOC)`
- [`fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) is the equivalent to `fetch_array(\MYSQLI_NUM)`
- [`fetch_object()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) returns each record one by one as an object.

  ```
  $row = $result->fetch_object();
  printf("%s (%s)\n", $row->myCol, $row->myOtherCol);
  ```

However, to keep it simple you can just loop on the `mysqli_result` directly which will get you each row as an associative array.

```
foreach($stmt->get_result() as $row) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["myCol"], $row["myOtherCol"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `fetch()` method on the [mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. It's not clear what you're expecting `fetch()` to return, but you're probably looking at the `fetch()` method of the [mysqli_stmt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but arent we using  `mysqli_result` in `bind_result` ? so why fetch working there?

Comment: No, `bind_result()` and `fetch()` are both methods on the `mysqli_stmt` object. You can either use `$stmt->get_result()` and then `$result->fetch_whatever()` *or* `$stmt->bind_result()` and then `$stmt->fetch()`. Two different ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: fetch() is not within mysqli_stmt according to the php manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php  So it cant be used with get_result. only bind_result because its from mysqli-stmt.prepare