# Mysql do not fetch multiple rows with same field value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables: categories and models. For now, categories table is important.

```
| id | nazwa | desc_s1 | photo | active | id_user |
|  1 | Audi  |   test  |  url  |   1    |    2    |
|  2 | BMW   |   test  |  url  |   1    |    2    |
|  3 | Ford  |   test  |  url  |   1    |    2    |
|  4 | BMW   |   test  |  url  |   1    |    2    |
```

And I have php:

```
$query_categories = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE nazwa='$selected_category' AND active=1 AND id_user=".$_SESSION['id_user'].";";
$query_model = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE active=1";

$result_categories = mysqli_query($con, $query_categories);
$result_model = mysqli_query($con, $query_model);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_categories) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result_model) > 0) {

    $row_categories = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_categories);
    $selected_category =  $row_categories['nazwa'];
    $_SESSION['selected_category'] = $selected_category;
    $_SESSION['title_content'] = $title_content;
    $_SESSION['price'] = $price;
    $category =  $row_categories['nazwa'];
    $desc_s1 =  $row_categories['desc_s1'];
    $photo =  $row_categories['photo'];

    $row_model = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_model);
    $selected_model =  $row_model['model'];
    $stan =  $row_model['stan'];
    $przeznaczenie =  $row_model['przeznaczenie'];
    $kolor =  $row_model['kolor'];
    $typ =  $row_model['typ'];

    $table = array();
    do  
    {
        array_push($table, '
            <tr>
            <td class="text-left">353</td>
            <td class="text-left">Stan|' . $row_model['stan'] . '<br />Przeznaczenie|' . $row_model['przeznaczenie'] . '<br />Kolor|' . $row_model['kolor'] . '<br />Typ|' . $row_model['typ'] . '<br /></td>
            <td class="text-left">' . str_replace(' ', '_', $row_model['model']) . '<br /></td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $title_content . ' ' . $selected_category . ' ' . $row_model['model'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $price . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . nl2br($row_categories['photo']) . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row_categories['desc_s1'])) . '</td>
            </tr>');
    } while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_model));
} else {
    array_push($errors, '<span class="badge badge-warning">Error</span>');
}
```

Its working but, the output table gives me 3 results, missing is the last one. I know the reason is the same name name like row id=2 but how to get all of the rows in result? I have tried with while inside while but it doesn't work as I thought.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Why do you use do/while? Just use foreach.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're fetching twice;

```
$row_model = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_model);
```

and

```
while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_model));
```

The first time gets one row, the second gets the rest. Refactor your code to use the fetch only one time. It is likely you can remove this entire block of code:

```
$row_model = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_model);
$selected_model =  $row_model['model'];
$stan =  $row_model['stan'];
$przeznaczenie =  $row_model['przeznaczenie'];
$kolor =  $row_model['kolor'];
$typ =  $row_model['typ'];
```

Instead of `do...while` like you have here:

```
do  
    {
        array_push($table, '
            <tr>
            <td class="text-left">353</td>
            <td class="text-left">Stan|' . $row_model['stan'] . '<br />Przeznaczenie|' . $row_model['przeznaczenie'] . '<br />Kolor|' . $row_model['kolor'] . '<br />Typ|' . $row_model['typ'] . '<br /></td>
            <td class="text-left">' . str_replace(' ', '_', $row_model['model']) . '<br /></td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $title_content . ' ' . $selected_category . ' ' . $row_model['model'] . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . $price . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . nl2br($row_categories['photo']) . '</td>
            <td class="text-left">' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row_categories['desc_s1'])) . '</td>
            </tr>');
    } while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_model));
```

Change it to a `while` loop:

```
while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_model))
{
    array_push($table, '
        <tr>
        <td class="text-left">353</td>
        <td class="text-left">Stan|' . $row_model['stan'] . '<br />Przeznaczenie|' . $row_model['przeznaczenie'] . '<br />Kolor|' . $row_model['kolor'] . '<br />Typ|' . $row_model['typ'] . '<br /></td>
        <td class="text-left">' . str_replace(' ', '_', $row_model['model']) . '<br /></td>
        <td class="text-left">' . $title_content . ' ' . $selected_category . ' ' . $row_model['model'] . '</td>
        <td class="text-left">' . $price . '</td>
        <td class="text-left">' . nl2br($row_categories['photo']) . '</td>
        <td class="text-left">' . nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row_categories['desc_s1'])) . '</td>
        </tr>');
}
```

**Warning!**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Yes I understand, but it doesn't takes any affect on the last row of categories table, and why it's not showing (the reason is the same name as row 2 but the names cannot be changed)

Comment: Can you clarify? What you're saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm still do not getting the last row

Comment: Did you comment out or remove that block of code? See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't recommend using while loop either. A simple foreach should be enough.

Comment: Why @Dharman? It is pretty typical to use a `while` loop to traverse query results.

Comment: `foreach` is simpler and can be used multiple times. `while` is more complicated for new programmers.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree @Dharman. In my experience, beginners have more issues understanding array traversal than anything else. YMMV. In order to use a `foreach` here the OP would have to fetch all (an array of arrays), then loop.

Comment: No, mysqli_result is traversable. There's no need to use any fetch method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250222/1839439) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000796/1839439) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811163/1839439) and many more of my answers. Adding the extra call to some fetch function is usually confusing. It's simpler to write `foreach($result_model as $row_model)` than `while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_array($result_model))`

Comment: @Dharman, thank you, foreach inside foreach solved my problem :)